# Override Ansible SSH login user with SUDO user

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a situation wherein it is required to override the default SSH ansible connection. We use Jenkins agents as the ansible masters and we have the SSH setup between the "JenkinsUser" (Jenkins) and the "TargetUser1" (Targets) and has been defined in the inventory file

```
[dev:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=TargetUser1
```

Now, in the same target machine, I have another set of tasks which are owned by "TargetUser2" and "TargetUser1" cannot have permissions to run those. But, the same "JenkinsUser" has the SUDO permission to "TargetUser2". My playbook looks like,

```
- hosts: dev
  remote_user: JenkinsUser
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: TargetUser2
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
```

Expected Result: JenkinsUser would SSH to target host and sudo to TargetUser2, overriding the default SSH setup to TargetUser1.

Runtime Result: SSH connection is happening as TargetUser1 instead of JenkinsUser whereas the remote_user: JenkinsUser should be overriding the default ansible_ssh_user

Ansible-playbook -vvv output:

```
TASK [setup]     
<xyz.somehost.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: TargetUser1 on PORT
22 TO xyz.somehost.com
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of user:

- **remote user** – Ansible makes SSH connection with this account
- **become user** – Ansible 'becomes' this user **after** SSH connection is established.

In your setup, Ansible always connects with `TargetUser1` and for a given play tries to become `TargetUser2` after connection using `TargetUser1` is made.

From you description I understand that you can connect to remote box with `TargetUser1` and can connect with `JenkinsUser` to become `TargetUser2`.
In this case, you can do the following:

```
- hosts: dev
  remote_user: JenkinsUser
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: TargetUser2
```

You can set `remote_user` and `become_user` for a play or specific task.

Comment: I don't think you will considered as "JenkinsUser" on the target host. The remote_user here will be "TargetUser1" to which SSH is established. I did try the above option, does not seem to be working. The ansible docs say, remote_user is the user that is logged into the machine, which in this case would be "TargetUser1".

Comment: Play vars have [priority](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) over host vars, so `remote_user: JenkinsUser` will override your `ansible_ssh_user=TargetUser1` settings; and Ansible will ssh with JenkinsUser to the remote machine. If this is not answer to you question, please improve your OP with `ansible-playbook -vvv` logs and highlight what is wrong there; that way you'll get more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your observed behaviour sounds very logical. `ansible_ssh_user` is the username to connect as whereas `became` method will be used only once already logged in to the host.

Some ideas you could try instead:

- add `sudo` rights for `TargetUser1` to become `TargetUser2` on `dev` or
- change `ansible_ssh_user` on fly during the play (e.g. using `set_fact`) or
- create separate host aliases for `TargetUser1@dev` and `TargetUser2@dev` or
- set `ansible_ssh_user` to `JenkinsUser` and use `become_user` `TargetUser1`/`TargetUser2` for *every* task

Comment: I understand that the become user will come into play once logged into the host but is it the target host user (TargetUser1) that will become or is it the user through which ansible runs (JenkinsUser)? The ansible documentation does not provide clear explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

inventory:

```
[dev:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=TargetUser1
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: dev
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e "ansible_ssh_user=JenkinsUser   ansible_ssh_pass={{JenkinsUserPassword}}
```

Ansible only deals with 3 users, local, remote and become. The become_user has to be from remote_user. My need was to have `local_user` become the `become_user` which is not possible and hence I had override the default `ansible_ssh_user` in the inventory in the extra vars. Now, the `become_user` will be from overrided `local_user`